# SQL Cache table layout - UPDATE / INSERT Performance

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am currently developing a web application where I need to implement some sort of data cache. I want to store this cache in an SQL database (mySQL 5.6)

One cache entry is always 35000 double values long and identified by an index from 1 to 35000.

My first attempt was to build a table which stores the header of the cache, for example the create date and the criteria when the cache is hit or need to rebuild and a second table which actually stores the data.

The header table has the following layout:

```
tb_cache_header
id (primary key) | cache_criteria | lock | create_date
               0 |              a |    0 |  2019-10-10
               1 |              b |    0 |  2019-10-11                    
               3 |              f |    0 |  2019-10-12
```

The second table has than following layout:

```
tb_cache_data

   id | data0 | data1 | data3
    1 |   0.1 |   0.3 |   0.5
    2 |   0.3 |   1.2 |   1.4
...
35000 |   0.2 |   3.1 |   2.1
```

So each column represents one cache entry and the number in the column name is stored in the tb_cache_header.id.

If i need to get data from the cache I am doing an SQL query of the tb_cache_header to find if the cache is hit and than query the column with the name data[tb_cache_header.Id] from tb_cache_data. If the cache is not hit I add a new row to the tb_cache_header and a new column to the tb_cache_data.
The column is than filled with a transaction called with prepared statements in php with for example `UPDATE tb_cache_data SET data4 = 0.5 WHERE id=10`.

This will take up to 20 seconds for updating.

So will it be better to use a other table format like this?

```
tb_cache_data

id | cache_id (foreign key from tb_cache_header.id) | data
 1 |                                              0 |  0.1
 2 |                                              0 |  0.3
 ...
 1 |                                              1 |  0.3
 2 |                                              1 |  1.2
 ...
 1 |                                              3 |  0.5
 2 |                                              3 |  1.4
```

And use than `INSERT INTO tb_cache_data (id, cache_id, data) VALUES (10, 4, 0.5)`

Is in this case INSERT / UPDATE faster and what column should than be the index for fast reading one cache entry?

Thank you
Maddin

Comment: Do you access/update the values individually (e.g. is the value in data4 alone useful to you) or do you always need the complete tuple (e.g. when you do something to your data in your app, do you always read values 1-35kby accessing data1-data35k, or do you (sometimes) only need to read data4), and if you write them, do you keep track of the changes and update only modified values, or do you write data1-data35k? Relational databases have a a lot of overhead, while caches only require a subset of what they provide, and it can be helpful (=fast) to identify which things you do not need.

Comment: I always need the full 35k of data (one column in the first tb_cache_data) when I read the cache. I don't update the cache direct. I always create a new entry. (So I always write the 35k values)